# Delete User alerts in sharepoint giving Access Denied?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I am trying to delete user alerts from `_layouts/sitesubs.aspx` page login with site collection admin account. It throwing to "Access denied" page.

Logged in user has full permission to the site collection. I am not understanding why this happening.

Please help me out.

**Update: I used alert.asmx web service also. It is throwing "Server Error".**

Update:

Logs

```
' 6ovk  Verbose    Console XML successfully loaded from SiteAction on page http://dev.org/_layouts/sitesubs.aspx.    
6ovm    Verbose     End OnLoad of XmlConsoleDataSource from file "SiteAction".   
8ofj    Verbose     Menu::OnLoad() - Was called. ID="SiteActionsMenu"    
8xfr    Verbose     PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x00000000, have 0x00000040  
8e2s    Medium      Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005   
8gs1    Verbose     Access Denied for /TIGS/ALIF/_layouts/sitesubs.aspx. StackTrace: Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility:Void HandleAccessDenied(System.Exception), Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal:Void HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(System.UnauthorizedAccessException), Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest:Void DeleteSubscription(System.String, System.String, System.String, Boolean, UInt32, Boolean, Int32), Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlertCollection:Void Delete(System.Guid), Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.SubsManageBasePage:Void DeleteAlerts(Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser, Boolean, System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder, System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder, System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder, System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeate...  
8gs1    Verbose     ...r, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater), Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.SiteSubsPage:Void BtnDeleteAlerts_Click(System.Object, System.EventArgs), Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPLinkButton:Void OnClick(System.EventArgs), Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPLinkButton:Void System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(System.String), System.Web.UI.Page:Void RaisePostBackEvent(System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler, System.String), System.Web.UI.Page:Void RaisePostBackEvent(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection), System.Web.UI.Page:Void ProcessRequestMain(Boolean, Boolean), System.Web.UI.Page:Void ProcessRequest(Boolean, Boolean), System.Web.UI.Page:Void ProcessRequest(), System.Web.UI.Page:Void ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(System.Web.HttpContext), System.Web.UI.Page...   
8gs1    Verbose     ...:Void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext), ASP._layouts_sitesubs_aspx:Void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext), System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep:Void System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute(), System.Web.HttpApplication:System.Exception ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep, Boolean ByRef), System.Web.HttpApplication+ApplicationStepManager:Void ResumeSteps(System.Exception), System.Web.HttpApplication:System.IAsyncResult System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object), System.Web.HttpRuntime:Void ProcessRequestInternal(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest), System.Web.HttpRuntime:Void ProcessRequestNoDemand(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest), System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime:Int32 ProcessRequest(IntPtr, Int32),      
0   Verbose     Releasing SPRequest with allocation Id {0AEEB070-7A62-4D59-A6D9-F5F62BC68F55}    
0   Verbose     Releasing SPRequest with allocation Id {9E124F41-3A29-48BD-ABFB-089EB6EB89C9}    
0   Verbose     Releasing SPRequest with allocation Id {49C107D3-D7FF-47D4-8410-6044593498B9}    
6t8b    Verbose     Looking up context  site http://dev.org:80/TIGS/ALIF/_layouts/AccessDenied.aspx in the farm SharePoint_Config    
6t8d    Verbose     Looking up the additional information about the typical site http://dev.org:80/TIGS/ALIF/_layouts/AccessDenied.aspx.     
6t8f    Verbose     Site lookup is replacing http://dev.org:80/TIGS/ALIF/_layouts/AccessDenied.aspx with the alternate access url http://dev.org.    
6t8g    Verbose     Looking up typical site http://dev.org:80/TIGS/ALIF/_layouts/AccessDenied.aspx in web application SPWebApplication Name=DEV - 80 Parent=SPWebService.    
6t8h    Verbose     Found typical site / (d4771114-7c8d-49fe-b697-7a388e77b501) in web application SPWebApplication Name=DEV - 80 Parent=SPWebService.   
880l    Verbose     ConnectionString: 'Data Source=spdbdev1\dev;Initial Catalog=SharePoint_Config;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False'    ConnectionState: Closed ConnectionTimeout: 15    
8acb    Verbose     Reverting to process identity    
8acc    Verbose     Current user before SqlConnection.Open: Name: INSIDE\sa_commpooldev SID: S-1-5-21-2651373318-460420032-838475144-1161 ImpersonationLevel: None   
8acf    Verbose     Current user after SqlConnection.Open: Name: INSIDE\sa_commpooldev SID: S-1-5-21-2651373318-460420032-838475144-1161 ImpersonationLevel: None    
880m    Verbose     SqlCommand: 'dbo.proc_getObject'     CommandType: StoredProcedure CommandTimeout: 0     Parameter: '@RETURN_VALUE' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: ReturnValue Value: ''     Parameter: '@Id' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '386869e5-fb7c-4000-b54f-30928bd7ba1b'     
880l    Verbose     ConnectionString: 'Data Source=spdbdev1\spedev;Initial Catalog=SharePoint_Config;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False'    ConnectionState: Closed ConnectionTimeout: 15     
8acb    Verbose     Reverting to process identity    
8acc    Verbose     Current user before SqlConnection.Open: Name: INSIDE\sa_commpooldev SID: S-1-5-21-2651373318-460420032-838475144-1161 ImpersonationLevel: None   
8acf    Verbose     Current user after SqlConnection.Open: Name: INSIDE\sa_commpooldev SID: S-1-5-21-2651373318-460420032-838475144-1161 ImpersonationLevel: None    
880m    Verbose     SqlCommand: 'dbo.proc_getObject'     CommandType: StoredProcedure CommandTimeout: 0     Parameter: '@RETURN_VALUE' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: ReturnValue Value: ''     Parameter: '@Id' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '45b66929-08b5-4715-8511-f9fb94f614ee'     
880l    Verbose     ConnectionString: 'Data Source=spdbdev1\dev;Initial Catalog=SharePoint_Config;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False'    ConnectionState: Closed ConnectionTimeout: 15    
8acb    Verbose     Reverting to process identity    
8xfr    Verbose     PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x00000000, have 0x00000040'
```

Comment: Did you check logs? anything there?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any web application policies set that would prevent this user from managing user alerts?

Have a look in Central Administration > Application Management > Policy for Web Application and ensure that you aren't in anything that includes the deny policy against the "Manage Alerts" site permission.